# What is the order of execution for nested silverlight transforms?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, transformation, silverlight-5.0

I am using CompositeTransforms in nested silverlight controls and seeing unexpected results.

Here is a simplified example of the XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContainerControl" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
  <Grid.RenderTransform>
    <CompositeTransform Rotation="{Binding Rotation}"/>
  </Grid.RenderTransform>
  <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="RoyalBlue" DataContext="{Binding Child}">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
      <CompositeTransform TranslateX="{Binding XTranslation}" TranslateY="{Binding YTranslation}"/>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
  </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

with very simple objects:

```
public class TestData
{
    public decimal Rotation { get { return 90; } }

    public TestChild Child { get { return new TestChild(); } }
}

public class TestChild
{
    public decimal XTranslation { get { return 20; } }
    public decimal YTranslation { get { return 30; } }
}
```

I would assume that the child object (the rectangle) would have its translation transform applied and then the parent object (the grid) would rotate the entire thing. However, this is not what I am seeing. What is the order of execution for a nested transforms? How can I easily force it to work the way I expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In researching this further, I have confirmed the bindings get resolved top down in the hierarchy. That is, the parent binding gets resolved before the children. I saw this by placing breakpoints in the binding code and seeing which was hit first.

However, what I have realized is that the binding resolution and rendering steps are separate. Just because the bindings occur in the wrong order does not mean the rendering happens in a way that is unexpected.

I have tracked down my specific issue to be related to something else. Still, I hope this example demonstrates some useful behavior.